# does npm still don't saving anything to speed up the installation of already installed modules?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, pnpm

I know pnpm and yarn reuse modules that we already installed, what, in not updated tutorials that i see, we see that this is something that pnpm and yarn came to fix in npm, which downloaded the modules from the internet every time we install it. This still a thing? Does modern npm save cache or something to speed up installation?

Comment: On Windows there are cached modules on `%appdata%\npm-cache` path.
If you remove the `npm-cache` folder the first installation will be much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, npm has a cache of package tarballs. It does not download the packages from the internet all the time. In fact, you can verify that by running `npm install --offline`.

The reason npm is slower than pnpm is because of other reasons:

- pnpm uses a content-addressable store. Each file inside the node_modules directory is a hard link to the content-addressable store. This makes pnpm faster and more disk space-efficient.
- also, pnpm is running the installation stages separately for every installed package. npm cannot do all these operations concurrently as of the current latest versions (v6 and v7).

[image]

There might be other reasons pnpm is faster but these 2 must be the most important ones. npm's cache is not one of the reasons.